# Change wkhtmltopdf.command.exec property in ICXT after installation

Tags: properties, websphere, ibm-connections

Having the latest version 4.1.5 of [ICXT for HCL Connections](https://help.hcltechsw.com/connections/api/icxt/index.html) installed on WAS 8.5, I need to change some properties. The [installation instructions](https://help.hcltechsw.com/connections/api/icxt/install-guide-preparations.html) said that we have a `icxt-install.properties` for installation, where we can set them. But it seems only possible during installation, not to change values which were already set.

How can I see what values are currently set and how to change them?

### Backgrund

It's an ICXT installation without [PDF export functionality](https://help.hcltechsw.com/connections/api/icxt/install-guide-preparations.html#PDF_Export), because this wasn't needed yet. But this has changed, so I want to enable it and develop some templates for our users. The selftest on https://cnxhost.internal/ic360/ui/selftest.html says

```
Is wkhtmltopdf installed? no
```

According to the documentation, I unpacked the binaries to `${CNX_SHARED_DIR}/icxt/pdfexport` and restarted the WAS Appserver where ICXT is installed. But it's still not working. I assume that a predecessor admin or dev of mine changed this location, so I'd like to make sure that it points to my desired `${CNX_SHARED_DIR}/icxt/pdfexport` path.

Answer (score 0):

The script `${ICXT_INSTALL_DIR}/icxt-prepare.sh` creates WebSphere Resource Entries. But just once during the installation. So we couldn't change the properties and re-run the script, as I assumed. To change it, open WebSpheres ISC web console and navigate through **Resources > Resource Environment > Resource Environment entries**

[image]

Now click in **ic360**

[image]

and **Custom properties**

[image]

Now you see a list of all the properties which were set by the installer. If some values were wrong (in my case `wkhtmltopdf.command.exec`), click on the entry and change the *value* field.

[image]

After conforming with **OK** and **save**, we need to restart the Appserver where ICXT is hosted in. If you don't know, look at the *WebSphere enterprise applications*, open any IC360 app and look in *Manage Modules*. In my case its *CustomApps*, which we can restart in **Server** > **WebSphere Applicationserver**.

Now reload the self test page and we see the wiki module check working fine:

[image]